# Issue with converting XML document to string array

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am getting 0 count result when i am converting XML to string array using XDcoument object to string array as per below

```
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load((dataStream));

var services = from s in doc.Descendants("Location")
               select (string)s.Element("Name");

string[] locationArray = services.ToArray();
```

doc is as per below

```
<Locations xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Location>
    <Name>Anywhere US</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>South Central US</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>Anywhere Europe</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>West Europe</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>Anywhere Asia</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>Southeast Asia</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>East Asia</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>North Central US</Name>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Name>North Europe</Name>
  </Location>
</Locations>
```

**What should be wrong with the code to fetch array of location Name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting problem this was.

Because of your `xmlns` namespace, the element names all have that namespace. This works:

```
 var locations = from s in 
              doc.Descendants("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure}Name")
                 select s.Value;
```

`locations` now contains all your locations

To make it more readable you could do this:

```
  var services = from s in doc.Descendants()
                 where s.Name.LocalName == "Location"
                 select s.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a namespace definition in you Locations element. So the name of the element is **{http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure}Location** and not Location.

If you remove the namespace definition from the Locations element then will your query execute correctly and return a count of 9 Location elements